Wireshark - Set columns for http2 from header or data packets
This question is about setting up columns in Wireshark while trying to analyze http2 tcpdump.
I am used to with setting up columns in diameter tcpdump, where we can select various fields and add them as columns to perform analysis on the data which is flowing. As shown in below screenshot
Diameter Packet display
Below screenshot is for http2 packet which i need to decode as json to see the fields, I want to add these into columns.
HTTP2 packet display
on google there don't seems to be any similar solution, so had to post here.
My first post :)
